# AppCompatDelegate#setDefaultNightMode() causing MainActivity to freeze after returning from SettingsActivity for API 23

Tags: android, themes

I've implemented a day/night theme for my app and added a ListPreference in my PreferencesActivity/Fragment to change it there. All works fine for API 24+, but not for API 23 (which is my minimum).

Problem: when selecting a different theme in the Preferences, then returning to the MainActivity, it applies the new theme and then freezes.

I'm seeing in my log, that the MainActivity is recreating itself, going through the lifecycle again, but calling onPause() right after the last onResume().

Starting PreferencesActivity from MainActivity:

```
06-02 23:29:17.795 11783-11783/com.package D/MainActivity: onPause()
06-02 23:29:17.815 11783-11783/com.package D/PreferencesActivity: onResume()
06-02 23:29:18.299 11783-11783/com.package D/RosterParentFragment: saving instance state with 2019-06
```

Switching theme:

```
06-02 23:29:29.853 11783-11783/com.package D/PreferencesFragment: Preference changed with key KEY_DAY_NIGHT_MODE
06-02 23:29:29.856 11783-11783/com.package D/PreferencesActivity: onPause()
06-02 23:29:29.870 11783-11783/com.package D/PreferencesActivity: onResume()
```

Switching back to MainActivity (by back-press or home <-):

```
06-02 23:32:26.209 11783-11783/com.package D/MainActivity: onResume()
06-02 23:32:26.247 11783-11783/com.package D/MainActivity: onPause()
06-02 23:32:26.248 11783-11783/com.package D/RosterParentFragment: saving instance state with 2019-06
06-02 23:32:26.254 11783-11783/com.package D/RosterParentFragment: onCreate()
06-02 23:32:26.254 11783-11783/com.package D/RosterParentFragment: savedInstanceState == Bundle[{android:support:fragments=androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerState@9a98da, androidx.lifecycle.BundlableSavedStateRegistry.key=Bundle[{}], SelectedYearMonth=2019-06, android:view_state={2131296460=FragmentPager.SavedState{f01b10b position=113}}}]
06-02 23:32:26.254 11783-11783/com.package D/MainActivity: onCreate()
06-02 23:32:26.266 11783-11783/com.package D/MainActivity: savedInstanceState NOT null
06-02 23:32:26.266 11783-11783/com.package D/MainActivity: got fragment from fragment manager
06-02 23:32:26.268 11783-11783/com.package D/RosterParentFragment: onCreateView()
06-02 23:32:26.353 11783-11783/com.package D/MainActivity: onResume()
06-02 23:32:26.366 11783-11783/com.package D/MainActivity: onPause()
```

(And it's this last onPause() that seems to be the culprit - not doing that for API 24+.)

After this, touching the screen will give a

```
W/ViewRootImpl: Dropping event due to no window focus: MotionEvent
```

warning and moving away from the app (home button for instance) gives

```
Performing pause of activity that is not resumed
```

Works fine for API 24+. Any ideas?

```
class PreferencesFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat(), SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
    private val dayNightMode: ListPreference by lazy { findPreference<ListPreference>(Preferences.Key.DAY_NIGHT_MODE)!! }
    private val dayNightModeEntries = App.instance.applicationContext.resources.getStringArray(R.array.preferences_theme_entries)
    private val dayNightModeValues = App.instance.applicationContext.resources.getStringArray(R.array.preferences_theme_values)

    override fun onSharedPreferenceChanged(sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences?, key: String?) {
        when (key) {
            Preferences.Key.DAY_NIGHT_MODE -> {       
                AppCompatDelegate
                    .setDefaultNightMode(
                        Preferences.getCurrentDayNightMode())
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        Preferences.default()
            .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this)
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        Preferences.default()
            .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this)
        super.onStop()
    }
}

object Preferences {
    object Key {
        val DAY_NIGHT_MODE: String = "KEY_DAY_NIGHT_MODE"
    }

    fun default(): SharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
       .getDefaultSharedPreferences(App.instance.applicationContext)

    fun getCurrentDayNightMode(): Int {
        if (default().getString(Key.DAY_NIGHT_MODE, null) == null) {
            // no DayNightMode selected - setting to MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM
            default().setValue(Key.DAY_NIGHT_MODE, MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM.toString())
        }
        return default().getString(Key.DAY_NIGHT_MODE, null)!!.toInt()
    }

    fun setCurrentDayNightMode(mode: Int) {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(mode)
        default().setValue(Key.DAY_NIGHT_MODE, mode.toString())
    }
}
```

Comment: Ordinarily, I would search the issue tracker, but it seems to be down at the moment... If you have not done so already, check it (perhaps tomorrow) and see if anyone has reported a problem. It's possible the issue is tied to your changing the night mode setting in a `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`, though ideally that would be supported.

Comment: I'll do that, thx!

Comment: @CommonsWare https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131851825 could well be the same issue.

Comment: @kazume No change according to the issue tracker, have you found a workaround?

Comment: For now, I'm just restarting the app programmatically for API 23 and below when switching theme.

Comment: I have the same issue. On api level 21 I'm getting black screen on back pressed. On api 23 previous activity loads properly, but screen doesn't respond to touch events.

Comment: Did somebody find workaround (other than restarting the whole app) for this?

Comment: In the last comment in the issue tracker, this issue is marked as "fixed" as of the 4th of February. I'm currently not active on Android, but maybe someone else could confirm it?